# Nomination comments on the activity tab

Tags: bug, design, election

When viewing the activity tab on my profile (.../679449/freshprinceofso?tab=activity), I noticed that some nomination comments don't adhere to the same style as the rest of the comments and appear enlarged:

[image]

This happens when using the "Request Desktop Site" option in Chrome.

App: Chrome 32.0.1700.99

OS: Android 4.4.2; Nexus 5 Build/KOT49H

Comment: Yes! This has been bothering me too!

Comment: The bug is the missing link, the nomination is actually a post behind the scenes, so the comments should indeed be displayed. As for large text size it's weird, probably something with your mobile device. There is combination of margin, padding and line height applied there so probably the mobile browser chokes on it sometimes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm curious as to *what* is duplicated ?

Comment: @FreshPrinceOfSO: Shadow Wizard found the dupe, I merely followed the chain down further.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah, that's extremely helpful.